# Active Directory Authentication Library with Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, adal

Which version from ADAL should have or is planned to have support for UWP style applications?

Current stable version (2.18.206251556) gives me exception:

> System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233082
>   Message=Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was
>   thrown.   InnerException:

When im trying to fetch token with following code:

```
    public async Task<string> GetOAuthTokenFromAAD()
    {
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(String.Format("{0}/{1}", ADALServiceURL, TenantDomain));

        var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(string.Format("{0}/", ARMBillingServiceURL), ClientId, new Uri(ADALRedirectURL));

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }
        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

And latest version 3.4.206191646-alpha gives me error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS1503  Argument 3:
>   cannot convert from 'System.Uri' to
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential'  CloudScheduler

If have understood it correctly UserCredential parameter shouldn't be required as paramater and it should be using URI type instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I managed to get this working for the sample Todolist app. The overload for AcquireTokenAsync now requires a new PlatformParameters option to be passed in. Once you add that your good to go.

```
var p = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always, false); 
AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, redirectURI, p);
```

Answer (score 0):

ADAL 2.18 should work with universal apps. What Win10/VS2015/Win10 tools versions are you using? Also, can you capture a log as explained in https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/master/README.md and post it here?
About 3.x - that's still an alpha. Please refer to https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-MultiTarget-DotNet for how to use its API - however you should not need to use 3.x - 2.18 should work.